# Same Page Database Results

Tags: php, mysql, html

SAME PAGE RESULTS: (xmain.php)

//FORM (working good)

```
<form name="search" action="xmain.php" method="post">
code,code,code,
```

// QUERY (working good)

```
   code,code,code,     
   <input type="submit" name="doSearch" value="doSearch">
```

//These are last 2 lines of my 15 line query - I have skipped the rest to save space:

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM $tableName $qryWhere LIMIT $start, $limit;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

// Table query results here.....

OK, although all code is working correctly ( Form is submitting variables, database results are correct, etc, there are 2 nagging problems:

1 - ALL database results are echoed when the page is first loaded. The page is refreshing from top to bottom without a stop in between - **I would like for NO RECORDS to be shown at first page arrival.**
2. Also, because of the top to bottom nature of this page,my option choices are being reset upon form submission. I would like to maintain selections until the RESET button - 
that I have on the page for that purpose is clicked.

I realize that the form by always refreshing upon itself, is causing the above problems.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! - see working sample here:

http://www.symbioticmusicpublishing.com/database3/xmain.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Only show something when something is actually posted, so surround with `if(isset($_POST['doSearch']){..` or something.
2. echo a value `<input .... value="'.(isset($_POST['thisinputname'])?htmlspecialchars($_POST['thisinputname']:'')">`

On more elaborate forms a session could be handy, not needed for simpler ones/forms always getting the post though. BTW, I prefer using GETs for listing data, makes it easier to share/link. POSTs for alterations, GETs for retrieving (and a few other methods for real REST).

Comment: IF do search button is clicked, perform query (else) what happens then?. Is there a way to send back up to the top? I'm confused due to my lack of knowledge...Thank you

Comment: After implementing # 1, I still get ALL the records in the database. I did not understand #2 - Thank you

Comment: Then you did not implement it right. If there is a new visitor, there shouldn't be a `$_POST['doSearch']` yet.... Impossible to say what you are doing wrong without actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Echo the retrieved values inside a `if statement` like Wrikken suggested. Check that your form submission button is actually clicked and only then echo the results.

If you're unfamiliar with the syntax take a look at ternary operator.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Also use GET if you are getting data from database. And POST when you are putting data into database. I guess the reason why goes beyond the naming convention but still it's a nice reminder: GET for getting and POST for posting/putting.

UPDATE

Sorry I didn't think this one through. Put the sql query inside a `if statement`. Put also the echoing of results inside a `if statement`.

```
if (isset[$_POST['doSearch']]){
  //make the query
}

if ($sql){
  //echo the results
}
```